# Spark Cassandra Connector has bad read performance, produces a lot of disk writes by kworker

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

**Some followups at the bottom**

I have a test installation of Spark and Cassandra where I have 6 nodes with 128GiB of RAM and 16 CPU cores each. Each node runs Spark and Cassandra. I set up my keyspace with the `SimpleStrategy` and a replication factor of 3 (i.e., fairly standard).

My table is very simple, like this:

```
create table if not exists mykeyspace.values (channel_id timeuuid, day int, time bigint, value double, primary key ((channel_id, day), time)) with clustering order by (time asc)
```

`time` is simply a unix timestamp in nanoseconds (the measuring devices the values come from are that precise and this precision is wanted), `day` is this timestamp in days (i.e., days since 1970-01-01).

I now inserted about 200 GiB of values for about 400 channels and tested a very simple thing - calculate the 10-minute average of every channel:

```
sc.
  cassandraTable("mykeyspace", "values").
  map(r => (r.getLong("time"), r.getUUID("channel_id"), r.getDouble("value"))).
  map(t => (t._1 / 600L / 1000000000L, t._2) -> (t._3, 1.0)).
  reduceByKey((a, b) => (a._1 + b._1) -> (a._2 + b._2)).
  map(t => (t._1._1 * 600L * 1000000000L, t._1._2, t._2._1 / t._2._2))
```

when I now do this calculation, even without saving the result (i.e., by using a simple `count()`) this takes a VERY long time and I have a very bad read performance.

When I do `top` on the nodes, Cassandra's `java` process takes about 800% CPU, which is OK because this is about half the load the node can take; the other half is taken by Spark.

However, I noticed a strange thing:

When I run `iotop` I expect to see a lot of disk read, but I see a lot of disk *WRITE* instead, all of which comes from `kworker`.

When I do `iostat -x -t 10`, I also see a lot of writes going on.

Swap is disabled.

When I run a similar calculation directly on the CSV files the data came from, which are stored in HDFS and loaded via `sc.newAPIHadoopFile` with a custom input format, the process finishes much faster (the calculation takes about an hour with Cassandra but about 5 minutes with files from HDFS).

So where can I start troubleshooting and tuning?

### Followup 1

With the help of RussS (see comments) I discovered that logging was set to `DEBUG`. I disabled this, set logging to `ERROR`, and also disabled GC logging, but this did not change anything at all.

I also tried `keyBy` as the very same user pointed out, but this also did not change anything.

I also tried doing it locally, I tried it once from .net and once from Scala, and here, the database is accessed as expected, i.e., no writes.

### Followup 2

I think I got it. For once, I didn't see the forest for the trees, because the hour I stated earlier for 200GiB is still about 56 MiB/s throughput. Since the hardware I run my installation on is far from optional (it is a high performance server which runs Microsoft HyperV which in turn runs the nodes virtually, and the hard disks of this machine are quite slow) this is indeed a throughput I expect. Since the host is just one machine with one RAID array where the disks of the nodes are virtual HDDs, I can't expect the performance to magically go through the roof.

I also tried to run Spark standalone which improves the performance a bit (I now get about 75 MiB/s), and also the constant writes are gone with this - I only get occasional spikes I expect because of shuffling.

For the CSV files being much faster, the reason is that the raw data in CSV is about 50 GiB and my custom `FileInputFormat` that reads it, does it line by line, and is also using a very fast string-to-double parser which only knows the US format but is faster than Java's `parseDouble` or Scala's `toDouble`. With this special tweaking I get about 170MiB/s in YARN mode.

So I suppose I should, for once, improve my CQL queries to limit the data that gets read, and try to tweak some YARN settings.

Comment: How long does the read take without the ReduceByKey. It looks like that should be forcing a shuffle. You could probably avoid the shuffle if you use the .keyBy method. See https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/16_partitioning.md#how-to-take-advantage-of-cassandra-partitioning-in-spark

Comment: I now tried it without `reduceByKey`, and with the `keyBy`: `sc.cassandraTable("mykeyspace", "values").keyBy[(UUID, Int)]("channel_id, day").count()` - and it is the same. Very slow read performance and write access like crazy. Can it be that I am seeing quirks of the architecture? This is a test installation running on a machine with 128 CPU cores and 1024GiB of RAM, and my instances are actually VMs running inside MS HyperV. (I inherited this machine and just did a quick setup, I thought about setting it up properly later - I know this setup isn't optional)

Comment: Are you logging somewhere? There should be 0 write activity with count.

Comment: Oh yeah, I just looked at my `/var/log/cassandra` and there is quite some debug logging going on. gonna turn this off and check again *head -> desk*

Comment: Followup: I now disabled GC logging and set all other log levels to `ERROR`, but there is still a lot of disk write. What I also find funny: running the same query multiple times always yields different numbers of tasks being run although the data in the DB does not change. Is this normal?